# React-Router 5 - BrowserRouter fallback redirect on page refresh only if there's no match

Tags: react-router

So far I have not bee able to find a way to redirect to `/home` if the router fails to match, when refreshing the page.  If you're on `Bar` and refresh, you will always go to `/home` instead of `Bar`.  Without the `redirect` you can refresh and stay on `Bar`.  Is there way to know when the `Switch` fails to match any of the defined routes?

```
<Switch> 
    <Route path={ '/foo' }>
        <Foo />
    </Route>
    <Route path={ '/bar' }>
       <Bar />
    </Route>                          
    <Route path={ '/home' }>
        <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path={ '/' }>
        <Redirect to={ '/home' } />
    </Route>
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define NotFoundComponent or redirect manually to '/' url.
Try to define routes like this, then you can redirect to /404 page when URL is invalid. I think this would be better solution.

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} />
    <Route path="/bar" component={Bar} />
    <Route path="/404" component={NotFoundComponent} />
    <Redirect to="/404" />
</Switch>
```

In you case

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/foo" component={Foo} />
    <Route path="/bar" component={Bar} />
    <Redirect to="/home" />
</Switch>
```

Hope this helps you to understand!

Comment: Was it helpful @nullsteph? If not, I am going to close answer because it can confuse others.